# css is not applied to the appended html elements

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I googled that css should be applied to new loaded elements automatically, but I was not able to figure out what's wrong with my codes.

[my web:][1]

When you scroll down to the bottom, it will load new post(s). The new loaded element is a closed posts, so there is a "closed" class in the `div#pin`, and the `opacity` (or `filter`) should be applied but it doesn't.

Comment: Make a fiddle demonstrating your problem..

Comment: ids are only allowed on one DOM-element but you are using it on multiply. You should change the #pin id to a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your newly created element has `opacity: 1;` in its inline style.

Because inline style overwrites class defined style rules, an opacity of 1 is the result, and not opacity of 0.5 as defined by the rule for the class.

If that is not possible: try modifying the view.css rule

```
.closed 
    {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    }
```

By adding `!important` you increase the priority of the rule.

Comment: thanks. But the inline opacity is add by isotope, don't know how to remove that...

Comment: @Harrison I updated the answer based on your comment.